# RS422 in C++ to talk to a stepper motor

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I'm writing a code in C++ to talk to a MDrive23 plus. I have it connected to the computer using a RS422 to USB converter. We can talk to the motor using IMS Terminal, but I want to code in C/C++. Has anyone does this? Is it possible? Does anyone know the header files to include? 
I tried talking to the motor in the way that a RS232 is programmed. But I wasn't successful.
Code:

```
            tty_attributes.c_cflag |= CREAD;
            tty_attributes.c_cflag |= CS8;
            tty_attributes.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;
            tty_attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
            tty_attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
            tty_attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ECHOE);
            tty_attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ISIG);
            tty_attributes.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
            tty_attributes.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
            cfsetospeed(&tty_attributes,B9600);
            cfsetispeed(&tty_attributes,B9600);
            tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty_attributes);
```

I had errors like:

```
             Symbol 'CREAD' could not be resolved. 
             Symbol 'B9600' could not be resolved. 
             Symbol 'CS8' could not be resolved. 
             Symbol 'ECHO' could not be resolved. 
             Symbol 'ICANON' could not be resolved. 
             Symbol 'ISIG' could not be resolved.
```

Comment: You need to include the right header files.  422 should work the same as 232, the hardware will just do stuff on its side to convert it to the proper signal levels.

Comment: Most libraries should let you treat the port as a file / stream.  As rm5248 commented, include the appropriate headers and link with the appropriate libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the above errors, but I have this error now:   make: *** [src/pH.o] Error 1
recipe for target `src/pH.o' failed